# How to install C4B_Freeproduct extension on Magento 1.9 Community Edition

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, installation

How do I upload this **extension** (C4B_Freeproduct) to **Magento 1**.

Can only find the code on **GitHub** and I don't know what to do with it for the **extension** to be installed.

I am really struggling and I have seen that you was involved with the **development** with it.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me.